# Writing a Unix filter using bash

Tags: bash

*If a Unix/Linux command accepts its input data from the standard input and produces its output (result) on standard output is known as a filter.*

The trivial filter is `cat`. It just copies stdin to stdout without any modification whatsoever.

How do I implement `cat` in bash? (neglecting the case that the command gets command line arguments)

I came up with

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS="" read -r line
do
  echo -E "$line"
done
```

That seems to work in most cases, also for text files containing some binary bytes as long as they are not null bytes. However, if the last line does not end in a newline character, it will be missing from the output.

How can that be fixed?

I'm nearly sure this must have been answered before, but my searching skills don't seem to be good enough.

Obviously I don't want to re-implement `cat` in bash: It wouldn't work anyway because of the null byte problem. But I want to extend the basic loop to do some custom processing to certain lines of a text file. However, we have all seen text files without the final line feed, so I'd prefer if that case could be handled.

Comment: You're probably better off chaining existing filters (like `sed` and `awk`) in a pipeline rather than trying to implement something like this in bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read lines from a txt file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897354/read-lines-from-a-txt-file-in-bash)

Comment: It won't work for a binary file that contains null bytes; a shell variable simply cannot store null bytes.

Comment: @chepner: You are correct, I noted that. It's not a problem for my use case, because I know there will be no null bytes. Will edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: @larsks Yes, I'm quite sure the problem can be solved using `awk`. However the custom processing I need to do is rather complicated and a bash script would be easier to maintain.

Comment: You can just use `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done` to take care of last line without newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to work with arbitrary binary files (since the shell cannot store null bytes in a variable), you can handle a file that isn't terminated by a newline by checking if `line` is not empty once the loop exits.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
if [ -n "$line" ]; then
    printf '%s' "$line"
fi
```

*In* the loop, we output the newline that `read` stripped off. In the final `if`, we don't output a newline because `$line` would be empty if the last line read by the `while` loop had ended with one.